# R - dbGetQuery and preserve comments

Tags: r, rodbc, r-dbi

It seems when I pass a comment to `dbGetQuery()` it doesn't send the comment to our database. Is there a way to preserve comments?
I'm trying track which apps on Posit Connect are sending which queries and trying to do something like this:

```r
library(odbc)
library(glue)

glue_guid <- function(x) {
  glue(
    "/*platform: rsc, id: {guid}*/ {x}",
    guid = Sys.getenv('CONNECT_CONTENT_GUID') # exists on RStudio/Posit Connect
  )
}

conn <- dbConnect(...)
sql <- glue_guid("select * from my_table")
# /*platform: rsc, id: */ select * from my_table

dbGetQuery(conn, sql)
```

So the questions are:

- Is there some better way to track SQL queries to apps from connect to our database?
- If not, is this approach ^^^ even possible?
- If not, could/should I make an issue and if so, which package? `DBI` or `odbc`? I think `DBI` is doing it [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/DBI/blob/5e1b308a6b5838d5f29937e337641eddc8217acc/R/sqlParseVariables_DBIConnection.R#L11C7-L12)

Comment: Which DB server are you using? Do you expect the DB server to receive the full query ` /*platform: rsc, id: */ select * from my_table`? How do you determine that this is not the case?

Comment: Thanks. We are using Netezza and I do not see the comments in the query history database (`histdb`) when I send it via `dbGetQuery()`. However, I do see the comments if I run it from DBeaver. I expect Netezza to receive the full query or some better way to match SQL statements to the content on Connect that generated the query.

Comment: OK, can you set-up a DSN on the Connect server and test if the comment makes it to the DB when using `isql DSN`? This way we can determine whether it is the ODBC driver or any of the R packages that strips the comments.

Comment: Finally got to test it and the comments get stripped out :(

Comment: That's to bad :-( If the comments are already stripped out by the driver, your best bet is to use client side logging.